# Plugin to format url_segment as a decimal

Tags: segments

Need to take the final url segment which is in the form of **group/index/1030** and format it to be **10.30** to signify a time.

Anyone know of a plugin? The only ones I've found format it as a price and assume it to be 1,030 or suchlike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpressionEngine have a variable {last_segment} to get the last segment of URL. You can use any Math plugin like "Simple Math" (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-math) and divide that last segment by 100.

```
{exp:simple_math calculate="{last_segment} / 100"}
```

Also, try by using PHPStringFun (http://engaging.net/products/phpstringfun) to format the number.

Comment: I ended up using the "Price Format" plugin which has an option to set a tax percentage and show the result. So just set this to 1 and it works like a charm! Thanks for the above suggestion...it came after I found this one but works too!